# Is it possible to rename a variable easily?

Tags: math-mode, strings

I have a very long document. If I decided to rename a heavily used variable say `$x$` to `$X$` or `$y$` or something else, would there be an easy way to rename the variable in my entire document? String replace doesn't help, since it replaces all my lower case `x` in the document.

Comment: Well, logical markup would help here: `\newcommand{\myvar}{X}` and `$\myvar$`. Of course, string replace is necessary anyway, but using it with `$x$`, although this would change occasions where $x$ should be kept (and x does have a different meaning --> query string replace is also possible)

Comment: I belive that there was an aswer here be @egreg that changed the catocde in math mode for `x` so that it woud get highlited as red so you could easliy spot it. But, I can't seem to find it and need to go... I belive it also showed that an x in a macro name woudl not be affected (such as in `\max`).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, wouldn't help, since the text is already written. ;-)

Comment: @Rob: That's why I said you need a replace anyway ;-) Thinking in advance is always a good idea, so use logical markup. I 've done right from the beginning when I started with LaTeX almost 20 years ago!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought I rather think of good notation and names in advance, because equations gets unreadable in math mode when you have to use tons of macros. However, I failed...

Comment: if i were faced with this problem, i'd rely on my editor's "search and replace" function.  (i use emacs.)

Answer (score 5):

It's much better to do a replacement, but you can get away with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`x
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{X}% or y or whatever as long as it doesn't contain x
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`x=\string"8000 }

\begin{document}

Extra $x=2\xrightarrow{f}3$

\end{document}
```

As you see, text is not affected, nor an `x` in a command name.

[image]

Comment: this is a very *dirty trick*, so i would not say it qualifies as "easily".

Comment: @barbarabeeton For me it's easy. 

Comment: i *now* that, but if if's not in the latex manual, it's not easy.  what you suggests would appear in appendix d of the *texbook*.  hence, by definition, *not easy*.

Comment: @barbarabeeton ahahahah

Answer (score 5):

As Christian Hupfer already stated in [his comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324484/is-it-possible-to-rename-a-variable-easily#comment792709_324484) it would be much better to define commands for variables *in advance* when it is not sure that the symbol will not change.

But if one has to do it later, [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) has a special RegEx syntax to find only stuff in math environments (which are known to WinEdt) which is

```
<something>\E{isMath}
```

So if you would like to replace all "x"es (in math environments) you could search for

```
x\E{isMath}
```

and simply replace it with e.g. `n`. Of course this would also find *all* "x"es (in math environments) so also e.g. the "x" in `\max`. Luckily there is the option `Whole words only` which indeed will only find "`x`" and not also "`\max`".

Here a screenshot of the Replace dialog showing the above search pattern and the used options.

[image: screenshot of WinEdt's Replace dialog]

Comment: Of course. I thought this was clear. But just in case it wasn't ,hopefully it is now. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Non TeX solution:**

If `x` is a math variable name, it won't be preceded or followed by another letter, otherwise it will be another math variable. This statement can be translated in a regular expression so you can search and replace `x` with `y` using `sed` (there are `sed` ports for windows OSs as well).

This command changes `x` to `y` in a `test.tex` file making a backup file called `test.tex.bak` (but make your own backups as well, preferably as archives, and/or move them some place else):

```
sed -ri.bak 's/(^|[^a-zA-Z\\])x([^a-zA-Z]|$)/\1y\2/g' test.tex
```

For preliminary tests, you can add other 'x' combinations you may think you used in your document to see an immediate result:

```
sed -r 's/(^|[^a-zA-Z\\])x([^a-zA-Z]|$)/\1y\2/g' <<< 'add here --> x  exer  exxe 2x3 x^3 {x} xx 2x x2 $x$ \x \xtest maxx x\ x/'
```

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to be the best solution.  I am still checking my rather large paper, but it seems to have been a perfect 1-second solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can replace `$x$` with `$X$`. This does not affect the lower case x included in a text.

Comment: Yes, if all occurrence of x are in the form "$x$". But often this is not the case...

Comment: When using a variable, you always should use math mode, even in text, to show the variable-"style".

Comment: @der_user: What about `\begin{align}  x .... \end{align}`? ;-) Neither your nor my approach with replace would work then

Comment: @der_user: Yes, of course. But instead of `$x$` OP could have `$y + x^2$` or whatever. Replacing just `$x$` wouldn't help.

Comment: True, didn't think about that. My fault.